# AlarmManager setting fail

Tags: android

My problem is when i set the time which after 2 minutes is 10:02 ,when i reboot the device several times, may be the time is 10:03 or 10:04 or 10:05 ,my notification always shows out everytime.

I want my notification shows just once after 10:02 , is alarmManager can't conrotl it for system?

If it so , how do i avoid this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I used alarmManager、SharePreferenes、BroadcastReceiver.

My MainActivity button function:

```
public void onClickSetup(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Starting setting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // after 2 minutes
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("msg", "play_hskay");

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

        long time=cal.getTimeInMillis();
        //Save the time for future
        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("time",MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().putLong("saveTime",time)
                .apply();
    }
```

My receiver for notification:

```
public class PlayReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bData = intent.getExtras();
        if (bData.get("msg").equals("play_hskay")) {


            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

            inboxStyle.addLine("message");

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

            Notification notification;
            notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.heart).setTicker("title").setWhen(0)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    //.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    //.setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                    //.setWhen(getTimeMilliSes(timeStamp))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                    .setContentText("title")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);
        }
    }

}
```

My receiver for reboot a device:

```
public class AlarmInitReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"Start~~~~",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // load system time for now. May be is 10:03、10:04、10:05
        long current = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        // load the time when i set it before.
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("time", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        long setTime = preferences.getLong("saveTime", 0);


            Toast.makeText(context,"Enter receiver setting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intentForSetTime = new Intent(context, PlayReceiver.class);
            intentForSetTime.putExtra("msg", "play_hskay");

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intentForSetTime, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setTime, pi);//setTime suppose is 10:02

    }
}
```

My manifests for Broadcast:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name=".PlayReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="play_hskay" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmInitReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: you need to reset all alarms on Device reboot completed.

Comment: How do i reset all alarms ? Can you show me some instances ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, without changing much of your code, you will just need to add a flag to sharedprefs  when the alarm event occurs i.e. PlayReceiver is invoked.

If the alarm is occurred earlier before rebooting then boot_completed receiver will check with the flag in the prefs whether it is already done.

Alarm can be then set/not set accordingly.

Cheers...!!

```
   public void onClickSetup(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Starting setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // after 2 minutes
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("msg", "play_hskay");

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

        long time=cal.getTimeInMillis();
        //Save the time for future
        //Code Edit
        SharedPreferences preferences=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("received",false).commit();
    }





public class PlayReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bData = intent.getExtras();
        if (bData.get("msg").equals("play_hskay")) {


            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

            inboxStyle.addLine("message");

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

            Notification notification;
            notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.heart).setTicker("title").setWhen(0)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                            //.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                            //.setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                            //.setWhen(getTimeMilliSes(timeStamp))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                    .setContentText("title")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);

            //Code Edit

            SharedPreferences preferences=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            preferences.edit().putBoolean("received",true).commit();
        }
    }

}




public class AlarmInitReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Code Edit
        SharedPreferences preferences=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isReceived=preferences.getBoolean("received",false);

        if(!isReceived)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Start~~~~",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // load system time for now. May be is 10:03、10:04、10:05
            long current = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            // load the time when i set it before.
            SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("time", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            long setTime = preferences.getLong("saveTime", 0);


            Toast.makeText(context,"Enter receiver setting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intentForSetTime = new Intent(context, PlayReceiver.class);
            intentForSetTime.putExtra("msg", "play_hskay");

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intentForSetTime, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setTime, pi);//setTime suppose is 10:02

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks responding , may i ask how to set a flag for SharePreferences ?

Comment: Use the same way you are using to store savetime key-value in shared prefs in your onclicksetup method. I just mean to say add any boolean or int value in shared prefs in your playback receiver with some positive value which will indicate that the alarm is already occured.
So the same value will be checked whilesetting alarm for PlayReceiver.

Here is an example for you,
you can use this in you PlayReceiver class,
 SharedPreferences prefs= this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
 prefsEditor.putBoolean("received",true).commit();

Comment: thanks @App developer , i try your code in PlayReceiver class , and getBoolean in AlarmInitReceiver .

The problem still there :(


If i getBoolean if (true) , it still receive and send notification



If i getBoolean if(false) , it will lost first notification when i set it.

Comment: Hey, I made those changes to your code what I was suggesting you. I changed your code in onClickSetup, PlayReceiver and AlarmInitReceiver Class. Replace the same in your source and test. Refer my edit above. Cheers..!!

Comment: It is still a problem for me recently .  Until I see your code and it works for me. Thanks for your help truly !  I got the issue about sharePreferences now.

Answer (score -1):

for my code i just need to start the service.. and i have used..

```
public void scheduleAlarm() {
        // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationListnerServiec.class);
        // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
        // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
                60000, pIntent);
    }
```

and for MyAlaramReciver class

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
    // Triggered by the Alarm periodically (starts the service to run task)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LocationListnerServiec.class);
        i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
        context.startService(i);
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome --------1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

just try may be it will help you .

Comment: Thanks for your responding , but your alarm is for repeating ,i think it is not much like my alarm.